# Spyder Variable Explorer: Disable Scientific Notation

Tags: spyder, scientific-notation

[image]

Any chance of converting those to non-scientific notation in Spyders Variable Explorer? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clicking Format and setting Float formatting to %.15g did the trick for me.

Comment: `%.15g` just displays more decimal places if that is considered "appropriate". You might want to look at `f` (non-exponential notation) or `e` (exponential notation with fixed decimal places. See also [printf format string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string).

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Good job finding that option!

Comment: Is there way to perform this non-manually? This is fine and dandy when working within spyder, but if one is done developing and wants to simply run will they encounter the same issue with resultant output?